# APNs error handling in ruby

Tags: ruby, apple-push-notifications, tcpsocket

I want to send notifications to apple devices in batches (1.000 device tokens in batch for example). Ant it seems that I can't know for sure that message was delivered to APNs.

Here is the code sample:

```
ssl_connection(bundle_id) do |ssl, socket|
  device_tokens.each do |device_token|
    ssl.write(apn_message_for device_token)

    # I can check if there is an error response from APNs
    response_has_an_error = IO.select([socket],nil,nil,0) != nil
    # ...
  end
end
```

The main problem is if network is down after the ssl_connection is established

```
ssl.write(...)
```

will never raise an error. Is there any way to ckeck that connection still works?

The second problem is in delay between ssl.write and ready error answer from APNs. I can pass timeout parameter to IO.select after last messege was sent. Maybe It's OK to wait for a few seconds for 1.000 batch, but wat if I have to send 1.000 messages for differend bundle_ids?

Answer (score 2):

At https://zeropush.com, we use a gem named grocer to handle our communication with Apple and we had a similar problem. The solution we found was to use the socket's `read_non_block` method before each write to check for incoming data on the socket which would indicate an error.

It makes the logic a bit funny because `read_non_block` throws `IO::WaitReadable` if there is no data to read. So we call `read_non_block` and catch `IO::WaitReadable` before continuing as normal. In our case, catching the exception is the happy case. You may be able to use a similar approach rather than using `IO.select(...)`.

One issue to be aware of is that Apple may not respond immediately and any notifications sent between a failing notification and reading from the socket will be lost.

You can see the code we are using in production at https://github.com/SymmetricInfinity/grocer/blob/master/lib/grocer/connection.rb#L30.